# Can't create a MembershipUser during MembershipProvider Initialize?

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider, membershipuser

In my custom implementation of a MembershipProvider, during the Initialize method, I am constructing a number of MembershipUser objects.  The MembershipUser constructor is given the name of the MembershipProvider being initialized.  The problem is that this constructor causes  another MembershipProvider to be constructed, recursively.

Basically, I represent users in my custom membership provider with MembershipUser objects, and I would like to load saved users from disk during Initialize.

I know I can implement a delayed load of users after Initialization, but this requires a check in each method. Is there something I am missing where I can create MembershipUsers independent of the provider?

Answer (score 1):

No you aren't missing anything.  You can't do this in the Initialize method.

Comment: Ya.  I have tried all sorts of things to get this to work.  For example, during Initialize, I attempted to add the current MembershipProvider (with reflection, overriding the readonly aspect of the collection) to the MembershipProviderCollection (the the MembershipUser constructor would not complain).  This caused a recursive instantiation of my MembershipProvider.  Evidently, when accessing the MembershipProviderCollection, it reads the web.config file to create the MembershipProviders.

So, I now construct the MembershipUser objects on demand, for functions which return them.